# If I treat my C code like C++ code, will it run like normal?

Tags: c++, c

It's what I believe to be a very simple question.

---

Context: I'm following a tutorial that allows me to run C++ code in Visual Studio Code, but I'm trying to run C code, not C++ code. The program I'm trying to run is a simple Hello World program (shown below), but this question applies to all C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!")
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are not the same and you should use a C compiler to compile your code instead.

Comment: C has some features (like variable-length arrays) that are not allowed in C++. You can write valid and correct C code that won't be compiled by a C++ compiler.

Comment: C and C++ branched from a common, that was at the time called C, ancestor decades ago. Since then C has evolved into a better C and C++ became a better C++.  Neither look exactly like the root from which they branched.

Comment: no https://godbolt.org/z/ETa8o1

Comment: Also worth noting that Visual Studio's C support is can be surprising. I believe they now support C11 but not C99.

Comment: `sizeof 'A' == sizeof(char) ? puts("C++") : puts("C");`

Comment: The trivial "hello world" sample you have shown gives the same effect in both C and C++.      For more complicated programs, there are examples of C programs that will not compile as C++, others which will compile but give observably different behaviours.   There are also some C++ compilers that support features of C even though those features are not valid in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C and C++ are different languages. And even though they share a similar syntax, the semantic meaning of certain constructs are different.

C++ incorporates a large part of C, but it also diverges. You *cannot* just assume that C code compiled as C++ will give the same result.

You can write code that is both valid C and valid C++ yet mean different things in the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

While C++ can be seen for the most part a superset of C, there are some constructions that are invalid C++ and others that have different behavior.

Instead of dealing with that, tell your compiler to target C instead of C++. All the popular C++ compilers also support C (at least one version).